# How to keep multiple menus with the same options in sync?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, menu, appkit

My application, obviously, has a main menu in the menu bar.  One of these menu items contains a submenu that is also available in a `NSPopUpButton` somewhere else in my app.

Until now I've just been duplicating the menu options (programatically) in code to make the popup button, but when I change the name of the selector, or the title of the menu items etc, I inevitably forget to also make the same changes in the popup button.

I'd like to define the menu in one place and use it in two.  Is this possible?

I tried this:

```
// Get the same menu used by the main menu
NSMenu *addMenu = [[[[[NSApp mainMenu] itemWithTitle:@"Project"] submenu] itemWithTitle:@"Add"] submenu];

NSMenuItem *item = [[[NSMenuItem alloc] init] autorelease];
[item setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:NSImageNameAddTemplate]];
[item setOnStateImage:nil];
[item setMixedStateImage:nil];

addButton = [[NSPopUpButton alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(2, 5, 26.0, 16.0)];
[addButton setPullsDown:YES];
[addButton setBordered:NO];
[[addButton cell] setUsesItemFromMenu:NO];
[[addButton cell] setMenuItem:item];
[[addButton cell] setArrowPosition:NSPopUpNoArrow];
[addButton setAutoresizingMask:NSViewMaxXMargin];
[addButton setToolTip:@"Add Files or Directories"];

// Use the same menu as the main menu
[addButton addItemWithTitle:@"Add"];
[[addButton lastItem] setSubmenu:addMenu]; // <--- Breaks here
```

Unfortunately this causes a runtime error with:

> 2010-12-19 02:56:11.571
>   MojiBaker[85384:a0f] *** Assertion
>   failure in -[NSMenuItem setSubmenu:],
>   /SourceCache/AppKit/AppKit-1038.35/Menus.subproj/NSMenuItem.m:695

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `-copy` made this work, but then I noticed all the keyboard shortcuts appearing the popup button, which looked weird, so I ended up just iterating the main menu's items and building it dynamically like so:

```
NSMenu *mainAddMenu = [[[[[NSApp mainMenu] itemWithTitle:@"Project"] submenu] itemWithTitle:@"Add"] submenu];
NSMenu *addMenu = [[[NSMenu alloc] initWithTitle:@"Add"] autorelease];
for (NSMenuItem *addMenuItem in [mainAddMenu itemArray]) {
    [addMenu addItemWithTitle:[addMenuItem title] action:[addMenuItem action] keyEquivalent:@""];
}
```